# Return output from completed command using RootTools

Tags: java, roottools

I'm trying to retrieve the output of commandOutput in order to pass it to another function, but commandCompleted is never ran. Any help?

```
Command command = new Command(0, "cat " + file){
    private String output;
    @Override
    public void commandCompleted(int id, int exitCode) {
        Log.d("Commands.Completed", output);
        Log.d("Commands.Completed", "ID: " + id + " & exitCode: " + exitCode);
        saveData(output);
    }

    @Override
    public void commandOutput(int id, String line) {
        output += line + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    public void commandTerminated(int id, String reason) {
    }
};

try {
    RootTools.getShell(true).add(command);
} catch (IOException | RootDeniedException | TimeoutException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `commandCompleted(int id, int exitCode)` implementation is missing

```
super.commandCompleted(id, exitCode);
```

could it be the problem?

If you imported `RootTools` as

```
import com.stericson.RootTools.*;
```

you could also be using `RootTools.Log` which is muted by default. Maybe try to use

```
android.util.Log.d("Commands.Completed", output);
```

just to exclude the case.